# Yii2 disable debug toolbar on specific domain

Tags: yii2

I need to dynamically show or hide this tool bar depending on the domain.
But don't know how to do this in Yii2. Is it possible?
[this toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUXvn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in your layout file:

```
if (class_exists('yii\debug\Module') && yii\helpers\Url::base() === '/my.domain') {
    $this->off(\yii\web\View::EVENT_END_BODY, [\yii\debug\Module::getInstance(), 'renderToolbar']);
}
```

But I suggest you to orient on environment value rather domain value. Because domains could be changed by time...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inherit `\yii\debug\Module` and override the `bootstrap` method.

Add a judgment condition to `$app->getView()->on(View::EVENT_END_BODY, [$this,'renderToolbar']);` in the `bootstrap` method, if `\Yii::$app->request->hostName` is the domain name you specify, skip this line. Example:

```
if ('www.example.com' !== \Yii::$app->request->hostName) {
    $app->getView()->on(View::EVENT_END_BODY, [$this,'renderToolbar']);
}
```

Finally, the debug module uses your own class

UPDATE:

To provide you with a simple example:

```
// Module.php
<?php

namespace my/test/debug;

class Module extends \yii\debug\Module {
    public function bootstrap($app) {
        // other code
        
        $app->on(Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST, function () use ($app) {
            if ('www.example.com' !== \Yii::$app->request->hostName) {
                $app->getView()->on(View::EVENT_END_BODY, [$this,'renderToolbar']);
            }
            $app->getResponse()->on(Response::EVENT_AFTER_PREPARE, [$this, 'setDebugHeaders']);
        });
        
        // other code
    }
}

// config/main.php or config/main-local.php
'modules' => [
    'debug' => [
        'class' => \my\test\debug\Module::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Could you explain more in what file I need to write this code

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/main-local.php` it's supposed you have this:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];
    $config['modules']['debug']['allowedIPs'] = ['*'];
}
```

So you have to change your environment to production in your file `web/index.php`

change this:

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

to

```
if ('www.example.com' == $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod'); //set production mode of application
}
```

`dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])` to see what is return :)

Or just add check in this file `config/main-local.php`

Comment: This won't work. When the `YII_ENV` constant is being defined the `Yii::$app` property has not been set yet. You need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of `Yii::$app->request->hostName`.